# faded, pale background color in UITabBar.background

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

guys, I am trying to customize UITabBar, but problem is that when I set up simple green background color in UITabBar.background, result is insufficient. Like something lies on background. Here it is look like:
[image: faded color]

UITabBarController is created in storyboard, but background color I set up in code. Here is appDelegate:

```
TabBarController* bc=(TabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
bc.tabBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
```

If I set up pictures on background and on items - they just almost invisible. I've tried playing with tint colors on the right bar in storyboard, but all was useless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar issue when programmatically creating the UITabBarController background color in iOS 8.  The problem was I was using backgroundColor when I should have been be using barTintColor.  Try this.

```
TabBarController* bc=(TabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
bc.tabBar.barTintColor=[UIColor greenColor];
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the transparency of the tabBar:

Swift :

```
self.tabBar.translucent = false
```

Objective C :

```
[[self tabBar] setTranslucent:NO]
```

Comment: Your Swift example would also be identical in Obj C :)

Comment: In Objective-C it's a better practice to use NO instead of false.

Comment: Either way works, I prefer "NO" but "false" is fine and will compile happily.

Comment: Nice! This is what was doing it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The same in Swift, iOS 9.

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 254/255.0, green: 200/255.0, blue: 93/255.0, alpha: 1.00)
```